# Why I get NAN value when I using torch.matmul for two Tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch

When I use `torch.matmul` for two Tensor, I get the `NAN` value. The code is as follows:

```
torch.matmul(recon_1.t(), x)
```

The shape of `recon_1` and `x` are `2708*1433` respectively, The run results are as follows
[image]

but when the code changed as `torch.matmul(recon_1, x.t())`, the result will not be a `NAN` value.
can anyone have any ideas for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already pointed out in [PengJv Nie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76769752/7395592), the two calculations are not the same, with `matmul(recon_1.t(), x)` leading to a 1433×1433-shaped result and `matmul(recon_1, x.t())` leading to a 2708×2708-shaped result.

The problem, however, cannot lie (or, at least, cannot only lie) in the values getting too large: this would result in values of `inf` rather than `nan`. Instead, I guess what you see is the combination of values that result in `nan` for being mathematically undefined – I will call them "collisions" in the following. Such collisions are `-inf + inf = nan` or `0 * inf = nan`, for example.

I guess, in your case, some such collisions happened in the first matrix product but not in the second. Without knowing the values in the tensors, it is not clear what *exactly* happened, but let me demonstrate in a brief example what I mean:

```py
from torch import inf, matmul, tensor

a = tensor([[inf], [-inf]])  # 2×1 tensor
b = tensor([[1.0], [ 1.0]])  # 2×1 tensor

print(matmul(a.T, b))  # Case 1: 1×1 result
# >>> tensor([[nan]])
print(matmul(a, b.T))  # Case 2: 2×2 result
# >>> tensor([[ inf,  inf],
#             [-inf, -inf]])
```

In the first case, we calculate the result as `inf * 1 + (-inf) * 1` and thus have the first mentioned collision (adding positive and negative infinity with the result being mathematically undefined). In the second case, no such collision happens, as we will only ever multiply infinities with ones, which is fine (i.e. has a defined result).

Answer (score 1):

The result of `torch.matmul(recon_1.t(), x)` which is shape of `1433*1433`, does not equal that of `torch.matmul(recon_1, x.t())` which is shape of `2708*2708`. The reason why all values of the first one is nan may be that 2708 numbers multiply and add which will reach to a too large number.